# Fatal error: Cannot declare self-referencing constant with MongoDB and Cakephp

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp

I have this error when I tried installing Cakephp in an amazon ec2 server:

Fatal error: Cannot declare self-referencing constant 'Mongo::VERSION' in /usr/share/nginx/html/lib/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php on line 107

I am currently using PHP 5.3.23 and MongoDB version 2.4.3

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a file with just `phpinfo();` in it and check to see if the Mongo php driver is listed as installed and active.

Answer (score 0):

This is weird bug that pops up for people now and then. The weird thing about it is that the constant being referenced has nothing to do with the actual issue.

When this happened to me everything was working fine. Then I upgraded to PHP 7.1.7 and this started happening.

I was able to fix this by removing a number of 'require_once' statements at the top of the file that contained the class with the constant in question. I am not sure of the exact cause, maybe a circular reference of some kind?